# IOS: Load a View Controller When App is Launched from Browser using url schemes?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uistoryboard

I am new to iPhone developing , My app is based on video conferencing, I have a task where an app should launch from browser using URL schemes. I have done it but problem is when app launched from  browser it should load particular view controller. I am using Storyboard. Here is the code which I tried.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if (!url) {  return NO;
    }

    NSString *URLString = [url absoluteString];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:URLString forKey:@"url"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    URLParser *parser = [[URLParser alloc] initWithURLString:URLString];
     username = [parser valueForVariable:@"USERNAME"];
    NSLog(@"%@", username); //b
    sessid = [parser valueForVariable:@"SESSION_ID"];
    NSLog(@"%@", sessid); //(null)
    tokenid = [parser valueForVariable:@"token"];
    NSLog(@"%@", tokenid); //yes
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    ViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VideoController"];

       return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is your storyboard based on navigation controller? or Tab bar controller? The problem is how to show a particular ViewController. Thats it. if its a navigation controller, you may want to push the ViewController(you want to open). If the initial view controller is a tabbarcontroller, you may want to change the selectedIndex of tabbbarcontroller.

Comment: its based on navigation controller

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it..

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    //get parameters
    [self goResetPassword:dict];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void) goResetPassword:(NSDictionary*) dict{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *root = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"resetPasswordView"]];
    self.window.rootViewController= root;
    ResetPasswordViewController *vc = (ResetPasswordViewController*)[[root viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    [vc loadData:dict];
}
```

hope it helps... GL HF

Comment: hey I tried to reach you from another post. How do I chat you? You asked me to post the code for the question I asked about segmented controllers

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment your initial ViewController is NavigationController. This is how you can push the required ViewController.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    // same code

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

// Get instance of initial Viewcontroller from storyboard
UINavigationController *navController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController
];
// Get instance of desired viewcontroller
    ViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VideoController"];
// Push ViewController on to NavigationController
[navController pushViewController:viewController  animated:NO];
       return YES;
}
```

Comment: I tried as u said. But Still When i launch it shows only initial view controller. not going to my desired view controller

Comment: Use Debugging. Is your handleOpenURL method getting called?

Comment: S its getting Called becoz it prints USERNAME SESSION_ID and token

Answer (score 0):

#### Check It

```
UIStoryboard *board             = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *nav     = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

[nav setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

IntroVC *initailView  = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Intro"];
[nav pushViewController:initailView animated:YES];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
UIApplication *sharedApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[sharedApplication unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
```