# How do I deep link and navigate to a "LogInLoading" screen while the OAuth token exchange request is made?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

Configuring my app to work with OAuth. Once I have the auth_code from the redirect uri, I want the user to be taken to a "log in loading" page, where a loading spinner is shown while the token exchange request is happening.

The app has been properly configured iOS side to allow deep linking, and I am being brought back to the app, just to the wrong page.

I have followed [the official](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html) deep linking guide from React Navigation, as well as various Stack Overflow pages and Medium articles.

This is my `App.tsx` component:

```
const prefix = 'myapp://'

export const App = () => {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Routes uriPrefix={prefix} />
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

This is my `Routes.ts`:

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ Onboarding: OnboardingFlowScreen, SignIn: SignInScreen })
const AppTabBar = createBottomTabNavigator({ Feed: FeedScreen, Create: CreateScreen, Profile: ProfileScreen })

export const Routes = createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator({
        AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
        LogInLoading: { screen: LogInLoadingScreen, path: 'auth_success' },
        App: AppTabBar,
        Auth: AuthStack,
    })
)
```

I should be brought back to the app and navigated to the `LogInLoading` screen. Am I misunderstanding? Shouldn't `Linking.openURL('myapp://auth_success')` take me to the page with path `auth_success` specified?

Comment: did you find any fix for android? as i'm also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The URL can only launch your application.

To take the user to a particular screen, you need to provide navigation context based on the URL.

Whenever your app is opened through a remote URL, you get a call back in `AppDelegate` in method `AppDelegate.application(_:open:options:)` Here you can navigate to the screen you want.

[Offocial Apple Documentation on URL Scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app)

Refer to a question here [IOS: Load a View Controller When App is Launched from Browser using url schemes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325372)